# Dropdown Menu doesnt stay when I hover over the tab so I cant navigate it - react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover

My nav component has a Games tab where a dropdown menu appears when you hover over it. However, I can't figure out how to keep the dropdown menu open as the user hovers from the games tab just below to the menu as there's a small gap so the menu disappears before u can move from the games tab to the dropdown menu.

Here is the relevant jsx code:

```
                    <li className='navbar__link' onMouseEnter={() => setIsDropdownOpen(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsDropdownOpen(false)}>
                      <Link to="/games" className='link__styles'>Games</Link>
                      <div className={`dropdown-menu ${isDropdownOpen ? 'show' : ''}`} onMouseEnter={() => setIsDropdownOpen(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsDropdownOpen(false)}>
                        <span className="dropdown-column">
                          <h3>Games</h3>
                          <p>Word games, logic puzzles and crosswords, including an extensive archive.</p>
                        </span>
                        <span className="dropdown-column">
                          <h5>Play</h5>
                          <ul>
                            <a href="link">
                              <li>
                                <img src={WordleIcon} alt="" className="dropdown-tile" />
                                <span>Wordle</span>
                              </li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="link">
                              <li>
                                <img src={CrosswordIcon} alt="" className='dropdown-tile2'/>
                                <span>Crossword</span>
                              </li>
                            </a>
                            <a href="link">
                              <li>
                                <img src={WordsearchIcon} alt="" className='dropdown-tile2'/>
                                <span>Wordsearch</span>
                              </li>
                            </a>
                          </ul>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
```

Here is the relevant css code:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 4px);
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 2% 8%;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar__link:hover .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-column {
    max-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-column > p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-tile {
    width: 25px;
    margin-right: 0.2rem;
}

.dropdown-tile2 {
    width: 17.5px;
    margin: 0 0.4rem 0 0.2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a little delay before closing the dropdown.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you  should remove onMouseLeave event of li tag and remove hover effect in css file and add show class in css file.
hover effect work through by toggling show class when show class is occure in then drowdon is show and when show class is not occure drowpdonw list is hide
then your drowpdown list is working properly
updated css code

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 22px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 2% 8%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}



.show{
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown-column {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-column > p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.dropdown-tile {
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
}

.dropdown-tile2 {
  width: 17.5px;
  margin: 0 0.4rem 0 0.2rem;
}
```

and updated jsx code

```
<li className='navbar__link'
         onMouseEnter={() => setIsDropdownOpen(true)} 
         
        >
          
                      <Link  to="/games" className='link__styles'>Games</Link>
                      <div  className={`dropdown-menu  ${isDropdownOpen ? 'show' : ''}`} 
                      onMouseEnter={() => setIsDropdownOpen(true)} 
                      onMouseLeave={() => setIsDropdownOpen(false)}
                      >
                        <span className="dropdown-column">
                          <h3>Games</h3>
                          <p>Word games, logic puzzles and crosswords, including an extensive archive.</p>
                        </span>
                        <span className="dropdown-column">
                          <h5>Play</h5>
                            <ul>
                        <a href="link">
                          <li>
                            <img src={WordleIcon} alt="" className="dropdown-tile" />
                            <span>Wordle</span>
                          </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="link">
                          <li>
                            <img src={CrosswordIcon} alt="" className='dropdown-tile2'/>
                            <span>Crossword</span>
                          </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="link">
                          <li>
                            <img src={WordsearchIcon} alt="" className='dropdown-tile2'/>
                            <span>Wordsearch</span>
                          </li>
                        </a>
                      </ul>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
```